# WPF DataGrid Databindung to MySql

Tags: mysql, wpf, datagrid

I want to bind a MySQL database to my WPF GridView.
But this doesn't work. I would like to do this:

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = table;
areaDataGrid.DataContext = table;
```

But the gid is empty. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` property

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article that walks you through exactly how to DataBind with the WPF DataGrid:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx